# Adding non-user determined variables to forms

Tags: php, html, forms, variables, post

I have a script that uses a loop (specifically "while") to produce many rows of data based on various rows of data in a SQL database.  This script also produces a form within the outputted row.  So that it ends up looking like this:

[image]

When users click the submit button it processes the data on a new page (ratinghandler.php).

That page will then change the a value in the associated SQL database.

My question is: if each row of output in the original page corresponds to a different row in the SQL database which is referencable by the "id" value of that row.  How can I associate the form with the correct "id" variable.  Is it possible to tell a form to post data which was not selected by the form operator (i.e. website user)?  How can i tell the page ratinghandler.php which row the submitted form corresponded to, if the forms are generated as part of a loop?

I hope I was clear I am happy to answer questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make the id a hidden field in the form.

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="X" />
```

Comment: Thanks.  So my follow up question is how can I make the value a variable.  I tried: